# Does adding a member to a Mongo replica set lock the primary/master?

Tags: mongodb

If I add a new member to a replica set, will this lock the primary as data transfers to this new secondary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort answer - No. You will not lock the primary when you add a new member, otherwise you couldn't scale up easily.